# How to add a Xbox One controller to the list of devices and printers of a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10, usb, vmware, vmware-workstation, xbox-one

**Context:**

I have:

- a Windows 10 virtual machine running on VMware Workstation Pro with a USB Controller set to `USB compatibility: USB 2.0`.

[image: USB Controller]

- a Xbox One controller.

[image: Xbox One controller]

- a USB to micro USB cable to connect the controller to the pc.

[image: USB to micro USB]

When the Xbox controller is plugged to the pc, a notification is seen on the pc. The Xbox Home button can then be pressed to open a Xbox gaming overlay. I can also see the Xbox controller in the Devices and Printers page.

[image: Devices and Printers]

Basically, the controller is detected by the pc.

When I go look in the virtual machine's plugged Devices and Printers, I don't see the Xbox controller listed like I do see in the pc and I can't use it.

**Question:**

Why can't I use the Xbox controller in the virtual machine? How do I add a Xbox One controller to the list of Devices and Printers of a Windows 10 virtual machine, running on a Windows 10 PC, with VMware Workstation 15 pro version 15.5.1 build-15018445 ?

I have tried to set the USB compatibility to USB 2.0 and tried 3 different USB to micro USB cables, but the problem still persist and the controller won't be detected by the virtual machine.

**Edit 0:**

I don't see the option to add usb devices in the `VM > Removable Devices` section.

[image: Removable Devices]

**Edit 1:**

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2176127#2176127

> [...] restart the VMware usb services.
> In my machine, it is called either "vmware-usbarbitrator.exe" OR "vmware-usbarbitrator64.exe"

[image: VMware USB service]

Comment: Your VM first needs a USB controller. Add that on the hardware tab. Second, you should add a new device of "Host USB Device" as well. This should pipe the controller through.

Comment: You have to attach the device to the VM.  This will disconnect the device from the host.

Comment: @Narzard see the edits (:

Comment: @Ramhound How do you do that on VMware Workstation? (:

Comment: @LoukMouk - “VM - Menu Bar -> Removable devices -> Connect” If the option isn’t there then the VM doesn’t have a USB Device or the required service isn’t running.

Comment: @Ramhound If you want to copy the answer I posted and put it as yours, do it, I'll give you the points for it (:

Comment: Machine also has to be running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the VMware USB Arbitration Service wasn't running on my host pc.

I just needed to restart this service. Go see the link in my **Edit 1** to see where I got the idea from.